# mpdf not generating pdf on production and testing server

Tags: php, html

I have a wierd problem. I'm developing an aplication that can create pdf files. The generating of pdfs works. But only on one site. If I first generate a pdf on the production it will work normally on production app but not on testing app. The opposite is also true. If I first create the pdf on the test it works normally on test but not on production. I'm 90% sure it's a browser issue. If I run the test and production on different browsers it works.
The pruduction and test are on the same website but in different folders and have different databases and database users.

Production functions code for generating pdf

```
$pdf_name = $name.'.pdf';
ob_clean();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $pdf_name . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

require_once 'pdf_templet.php';

$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0);
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html_pdf);    //is generated in pdf_templet.php   
$mpdf->Output($pdf_name,'I');
```

Testing functions code for generating pdf

```
$t = time();
$pdf_name = $name.'-'.$t.'.pdf';
ob_clean();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $pdf_name . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

require_once 'pdf_templet.php';

$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0);
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html_pdf);
$mpdf->Output($pdf_name,'I');
```

In the testing function I added a timestamp to the name of the fileand the function has a different name, but it still doesn't work.
Does some one know how to make it work?

Comment: It is highly unlikely the browsers are to blame. If anywhere in your code an error occurs your pdf will not show up normally. To debug this, do not open the pdf but save it, and then view the saved file with a text editor. If the file is empty then switch on error reporting in PHP. You can follow the normal debugging process.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Ok if I save it and try to open it I get that the file is corrupt. but opening it in notepad it's got the html code in it.

Comment: In the browser console I get the error Error: Invalid XRef stream header  pdf.worker.js:3841

Comment: But I've got nearlly the same function that saves a pdf to the server so you can get the files zipped. If I download those pdf they open  normally with no error.

Comment: @Your_first_response: Well, clearly there's something very weird going on. A PDF file should not look like html code at all. Are you looking at the correct file? The content of a PDF file starts with `%PDF` followed by a number. Check a valid PDF file, and see what it should look like. If you see html code, then this could be an error page, like a 404: Page not found.

Comment: the ones that are generated and saved on the server begin with %PDF-1.4%.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware after a little debugging I found out that the site stoppes working when it tryes to load the mpdf.php and it deosn't even get to my code. It fails at require_once('mpdf/mpdf.php');

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was loading the mpdf wrong. I was using as it was on examples on their site before it was closed. The documentation at github explains it well.

I loaded it

```
require_once(mpdf/mpdf.php);
```

correct way is

```
require_once(mpdf/vendor/autoload.php);
```

Now it works! Thanks @KIKOSoftware that made me debug my code step by step.

Comment: BTW, no need to call `header()` functions yourself, mPDF does this for you.